# Why does my Canon dSLR screen go black after taking two photos?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, rear-lcd

I have a Canon EOS 1300D/T6. The screen keeps going black after I take two photos. To fix it, I have to take the battery out and put it back in. The battery is fully charged. How do I fix this please?

Comment: By chance is it because of the timer you've set your screen to go back in order to save power? I'd suggest going through the menu and making sure you having got a timer for your screen to turn off.

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you tried half-pressing the shutter button / switching the cam on/off? Have you tried to reset the camera settings? Which mode are you in? Does the camera throw an error?

Comment: Also, try another battery. Even though the battery may be freshly charged, it might no longer be able to supply the needed current.

Comment: make sure you don't have the 'remove noise' setting on, this will analyse a photo and do a noise removal step which can take nearly a minute and make you think the camera is broken

Answer (score 2):

You "fix" it by taking the battery out and putting it back in.

Seriously, it does sound like a bug in your camera, but it could be caused by a faulty battery or resolved by changing settings related to how long the screen stays on after taking a shot. Or could it be that your camera starts sending the screen output to a connected device (a phone or tablet, via wifi?)

What you describe, going off after taking two shots, and requiring removing and re-inserting the battery (not just turning on and off the power), sounds like a real issue, not just a default being reset by removing and re-inserting the battery. So there are a few possible fixes:

1. You "fix" the problem by returning the camera to Canon (for in-warranty repairs).

or

2. You "fix" the problem by installing a firmware update in your camera (possible fix, but I'm not sure)

and/or

3. You experiment and see if any changes to possibly relevant settings fix the issue or change it (e.g. the display settings and/or pairing with a smartphone)

or

4. You just shoot and ignore that screen on the back of your camera.

Answer (score 1):

The touch screen to take pictures is on i had same prob and turned that function off and now its back working fine

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, just something you can do.

See if you can get another battery from a friend or something. If it works well on your camera, good, it is the battery.

If the problem persists, take it to a service center.

Just a tip, see if the contacts look clean.